# Every compact Riemann surface is smooth projective variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I was given a small project topic on writing a report on proving this result. I know that I need Riemann-Roch Theorem to show this, but I do not know any resource that explains the proof of this result using Riemann-Roch Theorem. Is there any expository on this?

Comment: You could also do this using the Kodaira Embedding Theorem, which is covered fairly completely in Griffiths and Harris if I recall correctly.

Comment: I think this is in Rick Miranda's *Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces*, probably chapter 5 or 6. The gist of it is that every Riemann surface carries a very ample divisor class which embeds it in some projective space, and Riemann-Roch is used to show that such a divisor actually provides an embedding.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's right. I guess the reason I didn't say this is because Miranda blackboxes the proof that there are "enough functions" on a Riemann surface. It depends on whether or not the asker is really interested in the analytic aspect of this or just how to deduce it from RR.

Comment: Just about any textbook covering analytical aspects of Riemann surfaces will contain a proof. Forster, Donaldson, Narasimhan, Napier-Ramachandran (if you want the most comprehensive one)...

Comment: You can see the book of Noguchi  (exercise 3 page 364). Analytic Function Theory of
Several Variables
Elements of Oka’s Coherence. I would be glad to share my solution with you.